# Clockwork task not running each full hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clockwork

I'm using Clockwork version 0.7.0 (yes, I know it's out of date), and I set a job to run each hour:

```
every(1.hour, 'My job', :at => '**:00')
```

But the job is running only once in few hours:

> 2017-09-17T00:00:07.701970+00:00 app clock.1 - - Clockwork: My job
>   2017-09-17T02:00:50.929599+00:00 app clock.1 - - Clockwork: My job
>   2017-09-17T04:00:43.244756+00:00 app clock.1 - - Clockwork: My job
>   2017-09-17T07:00:02.049012+00:00 app clock.1 - - Clockwork: My job
>   2017-09-17T09:00:05.517400+00:00 app clock.1 - - Clockwork: My job
>   2017-09-17T10:00:45.606928+00:00 app clock.1 - - Clockwork: My job
>   2017-09-17T12:00:21.329608+00:00 app clock.1 - - Clockwork: My job
>   2017-09-17T14:00:37.216280+00:00 app clock.1 - - Clockwork: My job

As you can see in the log, sometimes it runs every full hour but sometimes every 2 or even 3 full hours.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe is there bug fix related to issue like this? It very important to me that it will be reliable, and run the job each full hour.

Thanks.